# Unable to Update Data Templates in Sitecore Commerce 9

Tags: sitecore-commerce, habitat, commerce-catalog

I just installed a fresh instance of Sitecore Commerce 9.0 Update 1 and then start to play with Habitat Home (content and commerce). After installing all stuff when I go to the Content Editor under **Sitecore/Commerce/Catalog Management/Catalogs** I can't see the catalog but in Business Tools it is loaded correctly.

For fixing this I'm trying to delete **Delete Data Templates**, **Refresh Commerce Cache** and then **Update Data Templates**. 
But when I trying to do the **Update Data Templates** I'm getting following error:

[image]

> An error occured 
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   key at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey
>   key) at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogRepository.GetEntityView(String
>   sitecoreId, String viewName, String forAction, String itemId) at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.Templates.CatalogTemplateGenerator.BuildCatalogTemplates(Database
>   database) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj) at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args) at (Object , Object[]
>   ) at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.Job.DoExecute() at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object
>   state)

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs of the commerce roles or identity server?

Comment: Yes. 


_ERROR ClientCertificateValidationMiddleware: Certificate with thumbprint 75CC32EE7EE031DCC2E52838F874994F65C19C06 does not have a matching Thumbprint.
INFO ClientCertificateValidationMiddleware: Certificate with thumbprint 75CC32EE7EE031DCC2E52838F874994F65C19C06 is not valid._

I put the correct certificate and now works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

Corrected the certificate thumbprint in this two config files:

- **Sitecore.Commerce.Endine.Connect.config** from "habitathome.dev.local\App_Config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine"
- **config.json** from "\CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot